# Заполнение поля даты сделать опцианальным

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, model, django-model

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы заполнение поля дата рождение было не обязательным.
Добавила blank=True, null=True не помогает

```py
birth_day = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: А миграции вы после этого делали?

Comment: Да, делала. Не помогло

Comment: А в самой форме, где вы это вводите, не стоит обязательного заполнения? Как вообще ошибка выглядит?

Comment: default=None добавляли?

Comment: POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dv/Personel/personel/ 400 (Bad Request)   birth_day: ["Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DD."]

Comment: Нет, в самой форме нет обязательное заполнение

Comment: `birth_day = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)` и миграции попробуйте

Comment: Все равно выходит 400 ошибка

Comment: А как вы делалете миграции? Кеш чистили?

Comment: Нет, сейчас попробую

Comment: Не получилось=(